# data.table: preallocating memory for future columns

Tags: r, data.table

We have a very large `data.table`, to which we append columns, mainly by `data.table.merge`. Occasionally, this triggers a `"Cannot allocate vector of size xx Gb"` error, even though we know that there is this amount of memory available on the system.

Our suspicion is that this is due to the fact that this memory isn't part of a contiguous block, so we would like to somehow preallocate a larger chunk of RAM when creating the data.table.

One obvious suggestion is to just create all the columns that will be eventually merged into our data.table from another one at the outset. However, this isn't necessarily going to work, because `merge` is designed not to overwrite the columns of the `DT1` with those of `DT2` having the same name, but to rename them such that both can be kept.

Is there anything else that can be done?

Minimal example:

```
x = data.table(a = 1:10, b=2:11)
y = data.table(a = 1:10, c=2:11)

# want this to happen in the most memory-efficient way possible 
# and ideally without allocating new memory at all 
# (i.e., want to be able to pre-allocate enough memory in x 
# in line 1 to be able to do this)
x = merge(x, y, by=a)
```

Comment: `"Cannot allocate vector of size xx Gb"` doesn't mean that the amount `xx` is needed. It means that amount `xx` is needed in addition to what is already in use. I'm not sure you know that. Your suspicion probably doesn't apply.

Comment: `merge.data.table` at the moment copies DTs. What's the task you're performing (please provide a minimal example)? Would really help to implement [joins using secondary keys](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1130) asap.

Comment: You can merge and *add (lookup) column by reference* using `master_tbl[lookup_tbl, col := i.col]`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. 

@Arun, really useful to know that ```merge``` doesn't update by reference and indeed would be very useful for it to be able to do so.

@jangorecki, great suggestion - thanks!

Toy example: 
```x = data.table(a = 1:10, b=2:11); y = data.table(a = 1:10, c=2:11); x = merge(x, y, by=a)```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the minimal example and your expected result.

Comment: Have just done. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to be sure, you need a join operation (and can simply do `x[, c := y[["c"]]]`)? Your example doesn't make this obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the question from the code block: *"want this to happen in the most memory-efficient way possible"*.
The most memory-efficient you can get is to add columns to your `x` dataset by reference while doing join.

Since the recent [devel version of data.table, v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) you don't have to setkey before join.

```
library(data.table)
x = data.table(a = 1:10, b=2:11)
y = data.table(a = 1:10, c=2:11)
x[y, c := i.c, on="a"]
```

If you don't have the recent data.table version you have to setkehy in advance.

```
library(data.table)
x = data.table(a = 1:10, b=2:11, key="a")
y = data.table(a = 1:10, c=2:11, key="a")
x[y, c := i.c]
```